# opengl translatef

Tags: opengl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glui.h>

using namespace std;

GLsizei wh = 500;
GLsizei ww = 500;

void MyInit();    
void DisplayLine(void);    
void DisplaySquare(void ); 

void MyInit()
{
    glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 0 );
    glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 );
    glPointSize( 10 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity(  );
    glOrtho( 0.0, ww, 0.0, wh, -1.0, 1.0 );
}

void DisplayLine()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glBegin( GL_LINES );
        glVertex2i( 100, 100 );
        glVertex2i( 170, 170 );
        glVertex2i( 30, 370 );
        glVertex2i( 160, 50 );
    glEnd(  );

    glFlush(  );
}

void DisplaySquare()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
        glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
        glVertex2f( 150, 150 );
        glVertex2f( 350, 150 );
        glVertex2f( 350, 350 );
        glVertex2f( 150, 350 );
        glVertex2f( 150, 150 );
    glEnd(  );

    glFlush(  );
}

void DisplayRSquare()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

#if 0
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity(  );
    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( 50, 50 );
        glVertex2f( 250, 250 );
        glVertex2f( 50, 250 );
    glEnd(  );
#endif

    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
        glVertex2f( 500, 0 );
        glVertex2f( 500, 500 );
        glVertex2f( 0, 500 );
    glEnd(  );
    glTranslatef( 100, 0, 0 );

#if 0
    glRotatef( 20, 0, 0, 1 );
    glTranslatef( -50, -50, 0 );
    glColor3f( 0, 1, 0 );

    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
        glVertex2f( 500, 0 );
        glVertex2f( 500, 500 );
        glVertex2f( 0, 500 );
    glEnd(  );

    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( 50, 50 );
        glVertex2f( 250, 50 );
        glVertex2f( 250, 250 );
        glVertex2f( 50, 250 );
    glEnd(  );

    glRotatef( 12, 0, 0, 1 );
    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( 75, 75 );
        glVertex2f( 75, 550 );
        glVertex2f( 550, 550 );
        glVertex2f( 550, 75 );
    glEnd(  );

    glFlush(  );
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
        glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
        glVertex2f( 150, 150 );
    glEnd()
#endif

    glFlush(  );
}

void DisplayCube()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glVertex2i( 150, 150 );
    glVertex2i( 350, 150 );
    glVertex2i( 350, 350 );
    glVertex2i( 150, 350 );
    glVertex2i( 150, 150 );
    glEnd(  );
    glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glVertex2i( 250, 250 );
    glVertex2i( 450, 250 );
    glVertex2i( 450, 450 );
    glVertex2i( 250, 450 );
    glVertex2i( 250, 250 );
    glEnd(  );
    glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glVertex2i( 150, 150 );
    glVertex2i( 250, 250 );
    glVertex2i( 350, 150 );
    glVertex2i( 450, 250 );
    glVertex2i( 350, 350 );
    glVertex2i( 450, 450 );
    glVertex2i( 150, 350 );
    glVertex2i( 250, 450 );
    glEnd(  );
    glFlush(  );
}

void DisplayRotate()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity(  );
    for( int angle = 0; angle < 18; angle += 3 ) 
    {
        glRotatef( angle, 1, 0, 0 );
        if( angle > 8 ) 
            {
            glRotatef( angle * 2, 1, 0.0, 0 );
            glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
        }
        glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( 150, 150 );
        glVertex2f( 350, 150 );
        glVertex2f( 350, 350 );
        glVertex2f( 150, 350 );
        glEnd(  );
    }
    glFlush(  );
}

void pressMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if( state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        glBegin( GL_POINTS );
        glPointSize( 50 );
        glVertex2i( x, wh - y );
        glEnd(  );
        glFlush(  );
    }
}

void holdMouse(int x, int y )
{
    glBegin( GL_POINTS );
        glPointSize( 50 );
        glVertex2i( x, wh - y );
    glEnd(  );
    glFlush(  );
}

void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if( state == GLUT_DOWN ) 
    {
        mouseState = state;
        mouseButton = btn;
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;
    } 
    else 
    {
        mouseState = 0;
    }
}

void motion(int x,  int y )
{
    if( mouseState == GLUT_DOWN ) 
   {
        if( MouseButton == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON ) 
            {
            yrotation -= ( mouseX - x );
            xrotation -= ( mouseY - y );
        }
    }
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    glutPostRedisplay(  );
}

void DisplayFSquare()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 );
    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
        glVertex2f( ( GLdouble ) 0.25, ( GLdouble ) 0.25 );
        glVertex2f( ( GLdouble ) 0.75, ( GLdouble ) 0.25 );
        glVertex2f( ( GLdouble ) 0.75, ( GLdouble ) .75 );
        glVertex2f( ( GLdouble ) 0.25, ( GLdouble ) 0.75 );
    glEnd(  );
    glFlush(  );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize( ww, wh );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 150, 150 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Line" );
    MyInit(  );
    glutDisplayFunc( DisplayRSquare );
    glutMouseFunc( pressMouse );
    glutMotionFunc( holdMouse );
    glutMainLoop(  );
}
```

I have just created several trivial models to test the basic transformation. I have two questions:

1. DisplayRSquare : in this function I draw a square with the window size and want to move it to (100, 0), but it translated to (200, 0). And if I move it to (50, 0) it will move to (100, 0).

What more weird is, the program sometimes works and sometimes not.

1. For function `glVertex2f(0.3,0.7)`, we should find a point in the position 0.3*widthofthewindow, 0.7* height of the window, right? But I cannot find it. I have to compute the coordinates and run `glVertex2f(0.3*width,0.7*height)`.

My compiling command is  g++ -o line Line.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lglui
and just run ./line(File name is Line.cpp)

Comment: Can you just show us the code instead of explaining it, hard to follow what you wrote.

Comment: Generally, this all depends on the projection; so show it.

Comment: Actually I do not know how to attach the code. I try to copy& past here but the webpage ask me to indent 4spaces every line. I have more than 200lines in my program...

Comment: You can select the text you paste and hit the "code" button that will indent it for you.

Comment: Here is the code :http://carson529.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=c9GBIzgBAAA.c35O5TK1Wf_dTtc3BuQnbQ.ei6T6bIYcMAhA3ksbiFitA&postId=8067803993931881053&type=POST

Comment: Now I have posted the code.Thanks

Comment: http://carson529.blogspot.com/2012/06/opengl-gltranslatef.html

Comment: My compiling command is  g++ -o line Line.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lglui
and just run ./line(File name is Line.cpp)

Answer (score 3):

Please speak with me: *"OpenGL is not a scene graph! – It doesn't maintain a scene, and all it does is executing drawing commands, drawing single points, lines and triangles, one at a time."*

Your code lacks certain basic steps. First you need to setup a proper projection and modelview matrix. You put a projective matrix (ortho) in the modelview matrix at the beginning of your program. And then you just multiply, and multiply and multiply and multiply on the modelview matrix, without ever resetting it to a known (identity) state.

The coarse outline of every fixed function OpenGL display process is about the following:

1. set clear color and depth, then clear
2. set viewport and projection matrix

   1. matrix mode projection
   2. load identity
   3. multiply projection (ortho or perspective)
3. set initial view matrix

   1. matrix mode modelview
   2. load identity
   3. setup view (lookat or whatever)
4. draw geometry

   1. for each object
   2. matrix mode modelview
   3. push matrix
   4. apply local transformation
   5. draw object
   6. pop matrix

---

#### Update 1

First a rewriting of your program, that works in a predictible way and does what you originally indended.

Find answers to your questions after it

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void DrawRSquare(
    float sz,
    float tx,
    float ty )
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    /* 
       Order of operations matters.
       Drawing commands use the current state
       of OpenGL, which includes the transformation
       matrix state. So this must be set before
       drawing.
    */
    glTranslatef(tx, ty, 0);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
    glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2f( sz, 0 );
    glVertex2f( sz, sz );
    glVertex2f( 0,  sz );
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}

void Display(void)
{
    glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 0 );
    glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    const int windim[2] = {
        glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH),
        glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)
    };

    glViewport(0, 0, windim[0], windim[1]);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, windim[0], 0.0, windim[1], -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    DrawRSquare(50, 100, 0);
    DrawRSquare(50, 200, 100);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(
    int argc,
    char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutCreateWindow( "" );
    glutDisplayFunc( Display );

   glutMainLoop(  );
}
```

---

> Actually the program is running DisplayRSquare, in this function I draw a square same size with the window we created and want to more it with the vector (100,0) in the 2-D space but actually it translated (200,0). And if you change the vector into (50,0), it will move (100,0).

The reason for this is, that your Display function is probably called thrice and then no more. In the first call of DisplayRSquare a translation of (100,0,0) is applied after drawing some lines when the window is created but not yet exposed. Then the window gets exposed and the next redraw applies another (100,0,0) to the already set transformation. But still the window gets exposed another time and now the square will be drawn once again, now with the (100,0,0) + (100,0,0) applied. If you resize your window, the square would futher translate away until out of view with each redraw.

That's why you **must** reset your OpenGL state into a well known state before beginning any drawing.

> What is more wired, the program sometimes works well. Sometimes not. My code is glTranslatef(100,0,0). For the same program ,sometimes it translate 100, sometime 200......Kind of wired...

What happens is, that the amount of redraw events your programm receives varies. This is by moving other windows over it, iconizing and revertig it, etc.

> For function glVertex2f(0.3,0.7), we should find a point in the position 0.3*widthofthewindow, 0.7* height of the window, right?

This entirely depends on the set projection and modelview matrices. Without knowing how those are set, and your program never sets them into a well defined state, we don't know.

> But I cannot find it.

Quite likely, because your transformation matrices will be way off, of what you indended.

> I have to compute the coordinates and run glVertex2f(0.3*width,0.7*height)?

No. Well, at least not in the way you think.

---

A suggestion: You're using the fixed function pipeline and immediate mode. Both are severely outdated and deprecated. In fact they have been stripped out of recent versions of OpenGL, so I'd not even bother learning them.

If you want to learn modern OpenGL, I stronly suggest you read and work through the tutorial of Nicol Bolas, which is IMHO one of the best you can find at the moment:

http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Comment: can you please show me with an concrete example? just any polygon and woth a copy that is translated?like two squares?or just modify my program a little more?

Comment: So can you please tell me why this program can generate different pictures even if we run the same program?